# What's the use of the canonical factorization of functions?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, factoring

I've started reading Fuhrmann's *A Polynomial Approach to Linear Algebra* and have just seen the canonical factorization of functions:

> Given a function $f:A\to B$, the canonical factorization is $f=f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1$ where $$A\stackrel{f_1}\longrightarrow A/R \stackrel{f_2}\longrightarrow f(A) \stackrel{f_3}\longrightarrow B \\ f_1(a) = \{x\mid x\in A, f(x)=f(a)\} =: A_a \\ f_2(A_a) = f(a) \\ f_3(b) = b$$

I can see that $f_1$ is surjective, $f_2$ is bijective, and $f_3$ is injective.  However, while it is interesting that a function can be decomposed this way, I don't see any immediate application of this.  What is this factorization useful for?