# The canonical map from $\operatorname{coim}(f)$ to $\operatorname{Cdm}(f)$

Tags: set-theory

Coimage $\operatorname{coim}(f)$ of a function $f$ is the quotient set $\operatorname{Dom}(f)/\operatorname{ker}(f)$ where $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is the equivalence kernel
$$G(\operatorname{ker}(f)) = \{ (x,y) \in \operatorname{Dom}^2(f): f(x) = f(y) \}.$$
In other words, $\operatorname{coim}(f)$ is a partition of $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ where every cell is the equivalence class under the equivalence kernel of $f$.

There is a natural (=canonical) function $g$ from the coimage $\operatorname{coim}(f)$ to $\operatorname{Cdm}(f)$.

Let...

1. $\iota$ denote the [definite description operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description#:%7E:text=definite%20description%20operator);
2. $f^{\rightarrow}$ denote the [image function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Arrow_notation) of $f$,
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   f^{\rightarrow}: \mathcal{P}(\operatorname{Dom}(f)) \to \mathcal{P}(\operatorname{Cdm}(f)); \\
   f^{\rightarrow} = X \mapsto  \{ f(x) \in \operatorname{Cdm}(f). x \in X \}.
   \end{cases}
   $$

Then such function $g$ can be defined like this:

$$
\begin{cases}
g: \operatorname{coim}(f) \to \operatorname{Cdm}(f); \\
g = \underbrace{C}_{\text{cell of partition}} \mapsto \iota y \left(y \in f^{\rightarrow}(C)\right)
\end{cases}
$$

Does this function have a name? What's the common way to denote it?

As far as I understand, in Abelian categories there is a similar notion that is called image map. What is its set-theoretic counterpart?

Comment: What you're trying to describe is just the canonical factorization of $f$ induced by the universal property of quotient sets and one often denotes this by $\overline{f}$.

Comment: @QiZhu It looks like you're not the factorization of $f$ itself but rather the composition of its 2nd and 3rd factors, as I can tell from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893099/whats-the-use-of-the-canonical-factorization-of-functions Thank you a lot for this reply!

Comment: No, I am factoring $f$. Of course, one can always insert the canonical isomorphism $\operatorname{coim}(f) \to \operatorname{im}(f)$ in between and that's what the OP from your link calls $f_2$.

Comment: It looks like there is a minor discrepancy between the definitions. The 3-factor factorization seems more general but the 2-factor factorization has its pros too. I'll look more into that!

Comment: I found the theorem about it, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_Theorem_for_Sets